# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Ao tentar efetuar um INSERT na minha tabela com PDO, recebo o seguinte erro:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Já pesquisei bastante e vi alguns problemas parecidos, mas todos por falta de AUTO_INCREMENT na tabela, porem. Minha tabela tem AUTO_INCREMENT e está com a PRIMARY-KEY certinho.
Fiz até um INSERT na mão da mesma forma que está sendo feito no código e o INSERT funcionou.

Segue os códigos:

Query da tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios (
    usua_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    usua_email VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    usua_password VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    usua_status ENUM('ACTIVE', 'INACTIVE') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ACTIVE',
    data_create TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    data_update TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY(usua_id),
    UNIQUE (usua_email)
);
```

Trecho do código php que faz o insert:

```
        //INSERT
        $query = "INSERT INTO usuarios (usua_email, usua_password) VALUES (:usua_email, :usua_password)";
        $conexao = Database::getInstance()->prepare($query);
        $conexao->bindValue(":usua_email", $this->getUsuaEmail());
        $conexao->bindValue(":usua_password", md5($this->getUsuaPassword()));
        //Debug::dump($conexao->queryString);
        $conexao->execute();
```

Query radada com sucesso na mão:

```
MariaDB [memorando]> insert into usuarios (usua_email, usua_password) values ('mariombn@gmail.com','??????');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)
```

Comment: É com o php que dá erro?

Answer (score 3):

Verifique se sua coluna da chave primária da tabela esta como "auto increment", se não estiver altere, tive o mesmo erro aqui no meu Magento, solucionei desta maneira.

Answer (score 1):

**Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'**

Isto quer dizer que, de alguma forma seu código está enviando uma PK para gravar no banco, e este valor já existe. 
Para realizar um teste, tenta excluir o registro que está com ID 0.

Outro problema é você estar tentando cadastrar um usuário com um e-mail já cadastrado previamente, por causa do parametro **UNIQUE (usua_email)**

O melhor a se fazzer caso não seja isto, seria você printar no console a query antes do execute, para analisá-la.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.
Mas acredito que não sejá nenhum desses pontos. Até eu realizar o insert manual, não existia nenhum registro na tabela. Logo, também não é o ponto do campo usua_email ser UNIQUE.

Eu fiz um print_r na variavel de conexão antes da execusão mas a query é identica a que eu fiz no código.